# Displaying Items in HTML Table - Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have an html table to display list of items from my pivot table but my items are not being displayed like i want them. My items are being displayed in this format

**Table**

```
PatientID      Name    Doctor  City 

134            Joey    Michael London   Fredy  Amsterdam
```

But i want it to be displayed in this format

```
 PatientID      Name    Doctor    City 

134             Joey     Michael  London 

134             Joey     Fredy    Amsterdam
```

This is how my table with the for loops look like

**HTML**

```
    <table class="table"> 
        <thead>
            <tr>
             <th>PatientID</th>
             <th>Name</th>
             <th>Doctor</th>
             <th>City</th>
            </tr>

    </thead>
    <t

body>
 @foreach($patients as $patient)
<tr>
<td>{!! $patient->id !!}</td>
<td>{!! $patient->name !!}</td>
@foreach($patient->doctors as $doctor)
<td>{!! $doctor->name!!}</td>
<td>{!! $doctor->city!!}</td>
@endforeach
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just an issue in your structure in the end.
You want a row per doctor of a patient, so use two foreach loops after each other:

```
@foreach($patients as $patient)
@foreach($patient->doctors as $doctor)
    <tr>
    <td>{{$patient->id}}</td>
    <td>{{$patient->name}}</td>
    <td>{{$doctor->name}}</td>
    <td>{{$doctor->city}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
@endforeach
```

Bonus: You don't need the `{!! !!}` syntax unless you want to unescape your content (which is **dangerous** if it's user input!)

Comment: `you want to unescape your content` i didn't really understand this part. Could be really helpful if you could further explain

Comment: @LearnProgramming Well, if you'd output HTML content or similar from a database, you mostly want to unescape it so it will be rendered properly. Otherwise, blade will run the `htmlspecialchars` function on everything, which will prevent malicious user input that could hijack your page. (Look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#displaying-data) for further information.